# Apache OSX 403 Forbidden for Sub Folders

Tags: macos, apache

I can access my root folder in Sites:

```
http://localhost/~user/MySite/index.php
```

but files in sub folders such as /CSS or /images generate a 403 error. I read it could be permissions so I did

```
$ chmod -R 755 *.*
```

at the root folder, but that didn't help.

I'm using OSX 10.7.5 and Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.28 with Suhosin-Patch Server at localhost Port 80.

Do I need to somehow reconfigure Apache? This all worked out of the box with WAMP.

Thanks.

Comment: I just tried, with a subdir of 755 and a file within it, works fine here with the above mentioned permissions. I guess it is one of three different things, 1) Still incorrect permissions in some way, 2) Something related to which user runs the apache process, 3) A httpd configuration stating special permissions for that folder. OSX 10.9.5 and Apache 2.2.26, default apache with /Library/WebServer/Documents/ as documentroot.

Answer (score 0):

The chmod I used above did not recursively change permissions on sub folders. I ended up using:

```
find folderName -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

This changed the permissions on *folderName* and all subfolders.